# I like to change my id number to my post title in php

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I am using this function in php

http://domain.com/page.php?do=post&id=124

but i wish to change this URL to

http://domain.com/page.php/this is first post.html

How can I change this URL?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have knowledge of **`.htaccess`** to accomplish this.

What you need to achieve here is URL Rewriting.

> What is "URL Rewriting"?
>
> Most dynamic sites include variables in their URLs that tell the site
>   what information to show the user. Typically, this gives URLs like the
>   following, telling the relevant script on a site to load product
>   number 7.
>
> http://www.pets.com/show_a_product.php?product_id=7 The problems with
>   this kind of URL structure are that the URL is not at all memorable.
>   It's difficult to read out over the phone (you'd be surprised how many
>   people pass URLs this way). Search engines and users alike get no
>   useful information about the content of a page from that URL. You
>   can't tell from that URL that that page allows you to buy a Norwegian
>   Blue Parrot (lovely plumage). It's a fairly standard URL - the sort
>   you'd get by default from most CMSes. Compare that to this URL:
>
> http://www.pets.com/products/7/ Clearly a much cleaner and shorter
>   URL. It's much easier to remember, and vastly easier to read out. That
>   said, it doesn't exactly tell anyone what it refers to. But we can do
>   more:

You can find more information [**here**](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform url rewriting. Its a technique for you you need to configure your .htaccess  file.

Check this for [Details](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)